# Refactoring express side code into more consumable format

Tags: node.js

I am trying to be better at reformatting my code, and hoping someone can please let me know if I have done so correctly.

Here is my original copy

```
app.get('/lookup/:url', function (req, res) {
 country.init().then(function() {
    console.log(country)
    country.open(req.params.url).then(function(site) {
         site.analyze().then(function(results) {
            res.json(results)
            })
         })
     })
  })
```

Here is what I formatted it to:

```
app.get('/:url', async function (req, res) {
  
  try {

    await country.init();
    const site = await country.open(decodeURIComponent(req.params.url));
    const data = await site.analyze();

    return res.status(200).json(data);

  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex);
    return res.status(500).json({ message : "Oops." });
    
  }
```

Can anyone provide advice if I have done so correctly?

Comment: This is refactoring, not reformatting

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Does it look right however?

Comment: Sorry, I meant, you should change the title and your question to use the term refactor, not reformat, otherwise you'll confuse people as to what you're asking for help with. As reformatting, this is nonsense. As refactoring, then this is code-review and there is a stack-overflow site specifically for that https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: and, you should look into fat arrow functions as a way of removing the `function` keyword.

Comment: There isn't any fixed formatting standard for JavaScript, so you're not asking a yes/no question. I would drop the empty lines just before the closing braces and before `try`. Otherwise the formatting looks ok (ignoring that you both reformatted and refactored the code).